# input string was not in correct format while working with sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

Hi I written simple client socket application, where client send some string to server, server receives it and convert the string to upper case and send back to client. Client print the message from server to console. But When I ran the application, I am getting 'input string was not in correct format' error while converting the bytes received from server. Since I am new to C# programming, Can some one help me to understand why this error coming, and how to resolve it?

**Server.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server
{
    public class ServerSocket
    {
        private int port;
        private Socket serverSocket;

        public ServerSocket(int port)
        {
            this.port = port;
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);

            /* Associates a Socket with a local endpoint. */
            serverSocket.Bind(serverEndPoint);

            /*Places a Socket in a listening state.
             * The maximum length of the pending connections queue is 100 
             */
            serverSocket.Listen(100);
        }

        public void start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting the Server");

            /* Accept Connection Requests */
            Socket accepted = serverSocket.Accept();

            /* Get the size of the send buffer of the Socket. */
            int bufferSize = accepted.SendBufferSize;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            /* Receives data from a bound Socket into a receive buffer. It return the number of bytes received. */
            int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(buffer);

            byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];

            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = buffer[i];
            }

            String receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(formatted);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Data " + receivedData);

            String response = receivedData.ToUpper();
            byte[] resp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
            accepted.Send(resp, 0, resp.Length, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Press some key to close");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    class Server
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
            server.start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace client
{
    public class ClientSocket{
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private int port;

        public ClientSocket(int port)
        {
            this.port = port;
            clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        public void start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting client socket");
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
                clientSocket.Connect(serverEndPoint);

                Console.WriteLine("Enter some data to send to server");

                String data = Console.ReadLine();

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

                clientSocket.Send(bytes);

                Console.WriteLine("Closing connection");

                int receiveBufferSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[receiveBufferSize];


                int receivedBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[receivedBytes];

                for(int i=0; i < receivedBytes; i++)
                {
                    receivedData[i] = buffer[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(receivedData[i]);
                }

                String received = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedData);

                Console.WriteLine("Response : {}", received);

                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to close");
                Console.Read();
                clientSocket.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while connectiong to server {}", e.Message );
            }
        }
    }

    class Client
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientSocket clientSocket = new ClientSocket(1234);
            clientSocket.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to post your whole code give minimal example of your problem

Comment: I would start by googling the error message. I would then look at the call stack provided in the exception to see exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Response : {}", received);
```

should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Response : {0}", received);
```